Changing the environment used for external commands
In a shell, I can conveniently change the environment using Lmod, for example:
module load nvhpc

to load some particular package with compilers. Is there some way to change the environment from within emacs, so that the compile command will execute in this environment? I know that I can do this at startup by placing them in my .profile, but I want to be able to change the environment dynamically.

Would something like https://github.com/astoff/buffer-env help?

That looks quite promising indeed, but I have not managed to get the compile command to work with it (apparently some other packages/commands are then still required)
